# vue.js + Jest : how to test a form post?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

Until now I gave been using Avoriaz, but I would like to use Jest now ... 
found some tuts... but could not get any hint on testing my contact view component sending POST to an external urk...

```
    <form id="contactForm" action="https://formspree.io/mysite.com" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="_next" v-model="next" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_language" v-model="language" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Contact from my site" />
        <input v-model="sendername" ...>
        <input v-model="email" ...>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <textarea v-model="message" ...></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-gradient submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

As the external post URL is only valid for production...  I would like mock it and use the _next property as a callback page url...

any useful links to put me on first tracks ?? thanks a lot for feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prevent submit and post data using `axios` for example and then mock `axios`.

```
<!-- the submit event will no longer reload the page -->
<form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit"></form>
```

It's an easier way to unit-test that.